# How to fill MultiSelectList with a List<string> and List<int>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I want to have a listbox which gets filled in with a MultiSelectList. My viewmodel has the following properties for the MultiSelect:

```
    public List<int> SelectedID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    public List<int> ID { get; set; }
```

I don't want to have the Object in my viewmodel that's why I use a list of strings and ints.

In my controller I create the viewModel and fill in the list with the data I get from my database.

```
        myViewModel viewModel = new myViewModel();
        viewModel.ID = new List<int>();
        viewModel.Names = new List<string>();

        foreach(Var o in myData)
        {
            viewModel.ID.Add(o.Id);
            viewModel.Names.Add(o.Name);
        }

        return View(viewModel);
```

But in my viewmodel I've no clue how to insert it in my multiselect. Normally you put in the list with object want to go through but I don't have that, it's seperate in my case.

I know you can use ViewBag or ViewData to pass through the entire datalist but where I work it's not appreciated to use that.

Other way I thought about was to make a list in my viewmodel but I don't know if that's seen as a proper way to code in MVC.

I would appreciate the feedback thank you.

Comment: Why on earth would you not use the object? - `new SelectList(myData, "Id", "Name")`

Comment: I used the object way before but according to a few of my coworkers it wasn't safe to code object (models) in the viewmodel.

Comment: What! - of course it is. In any case you view model should contain a property for the `SelectList` e.g. `public SelectList MyItems { get; set; }` and assign it in the controller - `model.MyItems = new SelectList(myData, "Id", "Name")`, then in the view `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedID, Model.MyItems)`

Comment: Oke thank you. Looks like the easy way is also the correct way.